# JSF 2: Is it a good practice to use cookies instead of session?

Tags: java, jsf, session, jsf-2, session-cookies

I'm using JSF 2.0 and it's been a while since I've been searching for encrypted cookies as an alternative for session. I've heard there's something like this in "ASP.NET MVC 4".

So the question is: Is there any way to use cookies instead of session for storing data in 
JSF 2.0? If the answer is yes, is it a good practice or not?

I appreciate your comments.

Comment: One of the main disavantages of cookies is that users may disable them. I would not try to use them (unless there is no other alternative) for essential logic of your webapp outside of corporate environments (where you can control the client configuration).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the `setAttribute` and `getAttribute` HttpSession and that's what you want to replace with cookies, (presumably to save server memory), then you could just as easily save that data to cookies using `HttpServletResponse.addCookie` and `HttpServletRequest.getCookies`.

Now whether this is a good idea, depends on your usecase.

1. If you update the values in your session frequently, remember that you'll be sending the updated cookies with every response to the browser. This will increase the size of the response.
2. Cookies are stored on the client side, so they can be manipulated by the user too. Depending on your use, this might introduce security vulnerabilities in your application
3. Cookies can have a lifetime that's larger than a session. This could be useful depending on what you store in your cookies.
4. Using cookies allows Javascript to access the values, which can be good if you use it. But it also opens you up to Cross-site scripting.
5. Cookies can be disabled by users and organizations. So depending on who your users are, this could break your application if you rely on the data existing there.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your quick response. Is there any built-in method to save cookies encrypted?

Comment: No, you'll have to encrypt and decrypt the cookies on the server side. But if you're using the same salt for all cookies, a determined hacker could eventually get around your encryption. One solution could be to use a different salt for each user or even each session.

Comment: Additionally, consider Secure cookies. They are only transmitted over HTTPS connections.

Answer (score 0):

The way to use cookies is this one:

Writing to a cookie:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
 .getExternalContext()
 .addResponseCookie("CookieName", "value", null);
```

Reading the cookie

```
Map<String, Object> requestCookieMap = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
   .getExternalContext()
   .getRequestCookieMap();
```

I think there's no a "best practice", you should only consider that JSF use session in an extensive way, so the risk is that you have a great session size.
Cookies may help you avoiding too big sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are an important part of the web but generally I try to avoid using them for anything more than session management. If you don't want to store the users session on the server use client side state saving. You'll need to make any session objects serializable but presumably you were doing something like that anyway to store the state in a cookie. Unless your server is very memory constrained I'd just stick to server side session storage as it saves on bandwidth.